# Getting the Angular error on hot reload of webpack server to browser console for jhipster only, not at the other compilation

Tags: angular, webpack, jhipster, webpack-dev-server

I have a debug dev set up configured according to jHipster instruction https://www.jhipster.tech/development/ with proxy webpack server and broswersink. The server side works fine, the static files are pulled well from it and can be requested on `localhost:9000` and `localhost:9060`, but not the angular app itself when the `localhost:9000/` nor the `localhost:9000/api` is called on the browser tab under the browsersynk. I shows me the error in the browser console like this:

```
Error: Invalid configuration of route 'teacher/class/:id'. One of the following must be provided: component, redirectTo, children or loadChildren
    at validateNode (router.js?6580:607)
    at validateConfig (router.js?6580:577)
    at validateNode (router.js?6580:623)
    at validateConfig (router.js?6580:577)
    at Router.resetConfig (router.js?6580:4111)
    at new Router (router.js?6580:3779)
    at setupRouter (router.js?6580:5591)
    at _callFactory (core.js?09c9:18520)
    at _createProviderInstance (core.js?09c9:18466)
    at initNgModule (core.js?09c9:18396)
```

And it doesn't point to almost the same routes configured in the same file. I had no idea what is wrong with this specific route.

In one place I have a couple of routes configured like:

```
import { Route, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { CreateKindergartenclassComponent } from 'app/businesslogic';
import { DetailKindergartenclassComponent } from 'app/businesslogic';
import { ListKindergartenclassComponent } from 'app/businesslogic';
import { SelectKindergartenclassComponent } from 'app/businesslogic';
import { UserRouteAccessService } from 'app/core';
import { KindergartenClassResolve } from 'app/entities/kindergarten-class';
import { CommentResolve } from 'app/entities/comment';

export const createKindergartenclassRoute: Route = {
  path: 'teacher/class/create',
  component: CreateKindergartenclassComponent,
  data: {
    authorities: ['ROLE_TEACHER_PAID'],
    pageTitle: 'businesslogic.create.kindergartenclass.title'
  },
  canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService]
};

export const detailKindergartenclassRouteChild: Route = {
  path: 'child/class/:id',
  component: DetailKindergartenclassComponent,
  data: {
    authorities: ['ROLE_CHILD_PAID'],
    pageTitle: 'businesslogic.kindergartenclass.title'
  },
  resolve: {
    kindergartenClass: KindergartenClassResolve
  },
  canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService]
};

export const detailKindergartenclassRouteTeacher: Route = {
  path: 'teacher/class/:id',
  component: DetailKindergartenclassComponent,
  data: {
    authorities: ['ROLE_TEACHER_PAID'],
    pageTitle: 'businesslogic.kindergartenclass.title'
  },
  resolve: {
    kindergartenClass: KindergartenClassResolve
  },
  canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService]
};

export const listKindergartenclassRoute: Route = {
  path: 'teacher/classes',
  component: ListKindergartenclassComponent,
  data: {
    authorities: ['ROLE_TEACHER_PAID'],
    pageTitle: 'businesslogic.list.kindergartenclass.title'
  },
  resolve: {
    kindergartenClass: KindergartenClassResolve
  },
  canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService]
};

export const listKindergartenclassRouteChild: Route = {
  path: 'child/classes',
  component: ListKindergartenclassComponent,
  data: {
    authorities: ['ROLE_CHILD_PAID'],
    pageTitle: 'businesslogic.list.kindergartenclass.title'
  },
  resolve: {
    kindergartenClass: KindergartenClassResolve
  },
  canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService]
};

export const selectKindergartenclassRoute: Route = {
  path: 'child/select',
  component: SelectKindergartenclassComponent,
  data: {
    authorities: ['ROLE_CHILD_PAID'],
    pageTitle: 'businesslogic.list.kindergartenclass.title'
  },
  resolve: {
    kindergartenClass: KindergartenClassResolve
  },
  canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService]
};

export const listKindergartenclassCommentPopupRoute: Route = {
  path: 'teacher/classes/:id/delete',
  component: ListKindergartenclassComponent,
  resolve: {
    comment: CommentResolve
  },
  data: {
    authorities: ['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_TEACHER_PAID'],
    pageTitle: 'mentalApp.comment.home.title'
  },
  canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService]
};

export const listKindergartenclassCommentPopupRouteChild: Route = {
  path: 'child/classes/:id/delete',
  component: ListKindergartenclassComponent,
  resolve: {
    comment: CommentResolve
  },
  data: {
    authorities: ['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_CHILD_PAID'],
    pageTitle: 'mentalApp.comment.home.title'
  },
  canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService]
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is still unclear for me why, but everything started working in browsersync after I have splatted the large `*.route.ts` code into several ones:

```
import { Route, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import {
  CreateKindergartenclassComponent,
  DetailKindergartenclassComponent,
  ListKindergartenclassComponent,
  SelectKindergartenclassComponent
} from 'app/businesslogic';
import { UserRouteAccessService } from 'app/core';
import { KindergartenClassResolve } from 'app/entities/kindergarten-class';
import { CommentResolve } from 'app/entities/comment';

export const createKindergartenclassRoute: Route = {
  path: 'teacher/class/create',
  component: CreateKindergartenclassComponent,
  data: {
    authorities: ['ROLE_TEACHER_PAID'],
    pageTitle: 'businesslogic.create.kindergartenclass.title'
  },
  canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService]
};
```

and

```
import { Route, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import {
  CreateKindergartenclassComponent,
  DetailKindergartenclassComponent,
  ListKindergartenclassComponent,
  SelectKindergartenclassComponent
} from 'app/businesslogic';
import { UserRouteAccessService } from 'app/core';
import { KindergartenClassResolve } from 'app/entities/kindergarten-class';
import { CommentResolve } from 'app/entities/comment';

export const listKindergartenclassCommentPopupRoute: Route = {
  path: 'teacher/classes/:id/delete',
  component: ListKindergartenclassComponent,
  resolve: {
    comment: CommentResolve
  },
  data: {
    authorities: ['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_TEACHER_PAID'],
    pageTitle: 'mentalApp.comment.home.title'
  },
  canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService]
};

export const listKindergartenclassCommentPopupRouteChild: Route = {
  path: 'child/classes/:id/delete',
  component: ListKindergartenclassComponent,
  resolve: {
    comment: CommentResolve
  },
  data: {
    authorities: ['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_CHILD_PAID'],
    pageTitle: 'mentalApp.comment.home.title'
  },
  canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService]
};
```

and

```
import { Route, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import {
  CreateKindergartenclassComponent,
  DetailKindergartenclassComponent,
  ListKindergartenclassComponent,
  SelectKindergartenclassComponent
} from 'app/businesslogic';
import { UserRouteAccessService } from 'app/core';
import { KindergartenClassResolve } from 'app/entities/kindergarten-class';
import { CommentResolve } from 'app/entities/comment';

export const detailKindergartenclassRoute: Route = {
  path: 'teacher/class/:id',
  component: DetailKindergartenclassComponent,
  data: {
    authorities: ['ROLE_TEACHER_PAID'],
    pageTitle: 'businesslogic.kindergartenclass.title'
  },
  resolve: {
    kindergartenClass: KindergartenClassResolve
  },
  canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService]
};

export const detailKindergartenclassRouteChild: Route = {
  path: 'child/class/:id',
  component: DetailKindergartenclassComponent,
  data: {
    authorities: ['ROLE_CHILD_PAID'],
    pageTitle: 'businesslogic.kindergartenclass.title'
  },
  resolve: {
    kindergartenClass: KindergartenClassResolve
  },
  canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService]
};
```

and

```
import { Route, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import {
  CreateKindergartenclassComponent,
  DetailKindergartenclassComponent,
  ListKindergartenclassComponent,
  SelectKindergartenclassComponent
} from 'app/businesslogic';
import { UserRouteAccessService } from 'app/core';
import { KindergartenClassResolve } from 'app/entities/kindergarten-class';
import { CommentResolve } from 'app/entities/comment';

export const listKindergartenclassRoute: Route = {
  path: 'teacher/classes',
  component: ListKindergartenclassComponent,
  data: {
    authorities: ['ROLE_TEACHER_PAID'],
    pageTitle: 'businesslogic.list.kindergartenclass.title'
  },
  resolve: {
    kindergartenClass: KindergartenClassResolve
  },
  canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService]
};

export const listKindergartenclassRouteChild: Route = {
  path: 'child/classes',
  component: ListKindergartenclassComponent,
  data: {
    authorities: ['ROLE_CHILD_PAID'],
    pageTitle: 'businesslogic.list.kindergartenclass.title'
  },
  resolve: {
    kindergartenClass: KindergartenClassResolve
  },
  canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService]
};
```

and

```
import { Route, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import {
  CreateKindergartenclassComponent,
  DetailKindergartenclassComponent,
  ListKindergartenclassComponent,
  SelectKindergartenclassComponent
} from 'app/businesslogic';
import { UserRouteAccessService } from 'app/core';
import { KindergartenClassResolve } from 'app/entities/kindergarten-class';
import { CommentResolve } from 'app/entities/comment';

export const selectKindergartenclassRoute: Route = {
  path: 'child/select',
  component: SelectKindergartenclassComponent,
  data: {
    authorities: ['ROLE_CHILD_PAID'],
    pageTitle: 'businesslogic.list.kindergartenclass.title'
  },
  resolve: {
    kindergartenClass: KindergartenClassResolve
  },
  canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService]
};
```

still Angular magic for me and I still don't know what particular splitting has made the trick.